# High Scores. Is Saving a text file a good way?

Tags: java

I'm looking to add a high scores area to the game I am making. It would contain the users player name and there score.

Would the best way to do this is by reading and writing to a text file? Or is there a better way to do this? This will be a local high score table for now.

I have also looked and came across [this other users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248250/high-scores-table) question but it's for android (I know it's similar) and I'm still sort of new to programming so the way that is described in that question seems to complicated for me unless someone knows of a good tutorial or can explain how to do it.

Comment: Whichever is the least work :) For instance, it might be easiest just to serialize from a POJO to XML/JSON and store that in a text file. Consider what needs to be stored and how it needs to be accessed.

Comment: Should probably go on GameDev.SE because not much is mentioned about programming

Comment: Are the users likely to find the file and edit it by hand (e.g. to inflate their own score)?  If they did, would that be a problem?

Comment: @AndrewThompson it's so basically they can see what high scores they have gotten before. So editing it just effects them and it's no big deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends on the number of users in the table for a small number a text file should be fine if it gets big or needs remote access consider a database of some kind.

Comment: Why would a database be needed?

Comment: Its not necessary, but when a large number of datasets are supplied, using a database will allow for a much faster search among the data than a file would.

Comment: because it has more support for operations like querying and is easily extendible if the OP wants to add extra information about the user.

Comment: Well there shouldn't be to many entries in it. I'm not sure how easy it is to remove stuff from a text file but I could simply remove old low score entries I'm assuming?

Answer (score 0):

I have stored highscores several times. But that was in C++, but again you can do same in Java.
I always decide the Number of Highscores. Like TOP 10, or TOP 6, etc.

At the start of program check, if the highscore file is present, if not write 10 records in a new file.
When game gets over, read all 10 records, search for appropriate place for new highscore among 10 records. If it is say 4th place, create a new temp file, write first 3 records, then new record, then remaining 6 records. Note that last record will be effectively deleted.

NOTE : For even a 100 highscores(which don't make sense for a regular game), you don't need a database.